# Loading geopackage into mapView in Java?

Tags: java, software-recommendations, geopackage

Is there any way to load a geopackage file into any mapView in Java?

Is there any library to do this?

Comment: Check OpenJUMP and GeoTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy in [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) as GeoPackages are just another datastore type. So here is a modified version of the [QuickStart tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide.old/tutorial/quickstart/index.html) for a GeoPackage.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DataStore store = GeoPackageReader(args[0]);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource(store.getTypeNames()[0]);

    // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("Quickstart");

    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
    map.addLayer(layer);

    // Now display the map
    JMapFrame.showMap(map);
  }

  public static DataStore GeoPackageReader(String filename) throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, "geopkg");
    map.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, filename);

    DataStore store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
    return store;

  }
```

You can run through each of the feature types in the GeoPackage by looking at the typeNames returned from the store (rather than just taking the first as I have).

Comment: It seems to work but when I run your code and it reaches the line:
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource (store.getTypeNames () [0]);
I get "query does not return ResultSet" and when I start to trace, in this line of geotools GeoPackage class, is where the problem starts:
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery ("PRAGMA application_id")). 
Do you have any idea why I get that error? I have tried with several gpkg files and with none works.

Comment: can you add a link to an example GeoPackage that doesn't work?

Comment: For example I have tried with http://www.geopackage.org/data/states10.gpkg

Comment: works for me - just set the filename to point to that file (as command line arg in my code)

Comment: Reading the file is not the problem because when I execute another query on the file it returns a response, but when geotools executes the st.executeQuery ("PRAGMA application_id") statement it returns empty resultset

Comment: I think you need another question with your code in before I can get this

Comment: It could be with some version of the dependencies geotools uses, like sqlite driver or some other.

Comment: maybe I'm on 18-SNAPSHOT, but I don't understand what you mean when you say "execute another query". Please ask another question with details of your code and versions

Comment: I am using geotools 17.1, I solved the previous problem using sqlite-jdbc-3.14 but now I have another error when the functions ST_minX, ST_maxX, ST_maxX, ST_maxY and ST_IsEmpty are created in the Geopackage.java class, the error is: Unable to obtain connection: Error creating function.
But these functions are created several times when I am tracing and the first 3 does not give error, when going to pass by a fourth time is that I get that error.

Comment: you should just declare gt-geopkg as a dependency it will automatically pick up sqlite-jdbc 3.14.2.1 as required.